# Which Greek islande of the Cyclades is the most wild, or the most quiet?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, greece, islands

Which one of the Greek islands of the Cyclades is the most wild, or the most quiet?

Comment: Mathieu, to get this question re-opened you could add some of the island names that you are considering. For example "is A quieter than B?" or "does C have less development and towns than D?" are more answerable than this open ended version of your question.

Comment: I have visited some Greek islands and the most quiet (and fun) was Mylos. However, I don't think you can consider it "wild", since civilization is very present (small towns, crop fields, beaches, supermarkets, etc.), although in a very relaxed and stoic way.